# How to make this progress bar vertically in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I want to create this ui design in xamarin forms, as progress bar should look like this vertically.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path

Comment: You'll probably need to implement that yourself. You could also use SkiaSharp for this.

Answer (score 0):

To make the [ProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/progressbar) vertical, I have an easy solution for that.You can refer to the XAML below. It could help you.

**Xaml:**

```
<StackLayout Rotation="-90" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"> 

        <ProgressBar  Progress="1"  ProgressColor="Orange" >
            
        </ProgressBar>
</StackLayout>
```